# NodeJS - ExpressJS: How to stream request body without buffering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I need to handle some request without `content-type` as binary file

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: (req) =>  !req.headers['content-type'], limit: '500mb' }));
```

those file can be huge (eg. 500 MB).

I want to read `req.body` as stream for don't wast memory, but `bodyParser.raw()` make `req.body` as `Buffer`.

How handle `req.body` as `Stream`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use stream to handle huge file.

Express http request is a readable stream, you can pipe the request binary to file, but make sure the output is also a writable stream.

Example code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join('./uploadFiles', Date.now().toString() + '.mp4')));
    req.on('end', () => {
        res.end('Upload complete');
        next();
    })
})

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server listen to port 3000');
})
```

Comment: is this trade off worthwhile?